# Get modulus of each SSL certificate used by the server using OpenSSL

Tags: awk

My goal is to output the modulus of every SSL certificate used (both server and certificates in the chain) by the server. I use this bash script to get all SSL certificates from the server (in google.nl case, it's 3), and then using awk I split the it nicely into 3 (or less) different files each containing a certificate and calculate modulus of each of them.

```
a="$(openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.google.nl:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null  | sed -ne '/BEGIN/,/END/ p')" \
    | echo "$a" | awk 'split_after == 1 {n++;split_after=0}
    /-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ {split_after=1} {print > "cert" n ".pem"}'; \
    for i in `ls cert*`; do openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in $i; done
```

Now this solves my problem, but I feel like I am doing unnecessary work by saving certificates in files and so on. Can I somehow calculate modulus on the fly, without saving into the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit difficult, since `x509` only wants to process a single certificate, but it can be done:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.google.nl:443 | \
awk 'BEGIN { x509 = "openssl x509 -noout -modulus" }
     /-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/ { a = "" }
     { a = a $0 RS }
     /-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ { print a | x509; close(x509) }'
```